# How can I sort subarray of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, lodash, sub-array

I have a array like in below code:

```
[
  {
    "items": [
      { "name": "FRESH COCONUT WATER NAT PITCHER", "quantity": 50 },
      { "name": "COVERS", "quantity": 10,},
      { "name": "SPOONS", "quantity": 10,}, 
    ],
    "report_id": 60594,
  },
  {
    "items": [
      {"name": "FRESH COCONUT WATER NAT PITCHER","quantity": 50,},
      {"name": "COVERS", "quantity": 10,},
      {"name": "SPOONS", "quantity": 10,},
    ],
    "report_id": 60594,
  },
  
]
```

I need to sort the items array objects by their name in ascending order(A-Z)

I have tried using lodash but got no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try with [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: "tried using lodash" - may you share this?

Comment: Read [ask] and create a [mcve]

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `sortBy` function of [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#sortBy).

```js
var users = [
  { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 48 },
  { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36 },
  { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 40 },
  { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 34 }
];
 
_.sortBy(users, [function(o) { return o.user; }]);
// => objects for [['barney', 36], ['barney', 34], ['fred', 48], ['fred', 40]]
```